# Is there such thing as a 'Bubble Gum' dragon on Dragon City?

Tags: dragon-city

I tried to breed for it, but it always ends up something else.

Comment: Hi @user118668, and welcome! Here on Arqade, we prefer questions that show some kind of effort being made first. The reason you keep getting downvoted is because of this. Try moving your mouse over the down arrow, you should get the tooltip: *"This question does not show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful"*. Can you edit your question with the steps you tried to get the Bubble Gum dragon? If you do so, you'll find you get a more positive response from the users here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something called the Gummy Dragon, which people also seem to refer to as the Bubble Gum Dragon. It seems that from [this guide](http://dragoncityguide.net/how-to-breed-gummy/) you have the best chances of getting it if you breed a nature dragon with a double electric dragon, or a electric dragon with a double nature dragon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a gummy dragon and it is breedable. By breeding the double nature dragon with the electric dragon or by breeding the double electric dragon with the nature dragon, you will get a 100% success. Other options are also available, but the chances for success is lower.

Answer (score -2):

hi there are 2 possibilities to get gummy dragon 
first by breeding Star dragon and plant
second by breeding firebird and star 
You might also consider taking a look at [this guide](http://dragoncityeggguide.com/dragoncity-breeding-list-chart-guide/) which will help you understand it better